# How to extract a variable from Helm env config (within a deployment) and pass it as an arg

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have a helm chart

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: {{ include "xyz.fullname" . }}
  labels:
    {{- include "xyz.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicas }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      {{- include "xyz.selectorLabels" . | nindent 6 }}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        {{- include "xyz.selectorLabels" . | nindent 8 }}
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: {{ include "xyz.fullname" . }}
      containers:
      - name: {{ include "ixyz.fullname" . }}
        image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag}}"
        imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
        args:
          - --partition-number
          - "{{ (splitList “-”  PODNAME) | last | quote }}"

        envFrom:
          - name: POD_NAME
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: metadata.name
```

I want to extract the number from the pod name.
pod_name is something like abc-123
I want to pass 123 to partition-number but I am getting INVALID Yaml at  `- "{{ (splitList “-”  PODNAME) | last | quote }}"`.

I cannot use https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/labels-annotations-taints/#apps-kubernetes.io-pod-index as my k8 doesnt support it

I tried
I cannot use https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/labels-annotations-taints/#apps-kubernetes.io-pod-index as my k8 doesnt support it
Various version of spliting, using regex

Answer (score 0):

Things happen in a fairly specific order here:

1. Helm runs its templating engine over all of the `templates/*.yaml` files, and resolves *all* of the `{{ ... }}` template blocks.
2. Helm sends the resulting YAML to the cluster.
3. Kubernetes creates the Deployment object as shown.
4. Kubernetes creates Pods from the Deployment.

By the time you're creating Pods, Helm is no longer involved, none of the templating markup should remain, and Kubernetes isn't running a template engine.

The specific case you're describing is a little hard to do.  Kubernetes itself can substitute an environment variable value with syntax like `env: [{ value: '$(OTHER_VAR)' }]`, but it can't do any more processing on it.  You probably need to run a script inside your container to extract this value, maybe running it as an entrypoint wrapper script.  [Replication Controller replica ID in an environment variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52389771/replication-controller-replica-id-in-an-environment-variable) has a Kubernetes-specific example using an init container.

It looks like your image uses the "entrypoint-as-command" pattern, so your Kubernetes YAML only has arguments but not a command.  If you can repeat the command, then you can possibly use shell substitution here

```yaml
command:
  - /bin/sh
  - -c
  - >-
      PARTITION=$(echo "$POD_NAME" | sed 's/.*-//')
      the_command --partition-number "$PARTITION"
```

but you would have to find out what `the_command` is from the image.