# How to create a secret in the k8s cluster from a pod's container?

Tags: kubernetes, environment-variables, containers, kubectl, kubernetes-secrets

I am deploying my application in kubernetes using helm chart with 2 sub-charts `app` and `test`.

I have the pod of `app` chart properly running.
But `test` pod will be running only if it can properly authenticate to `app` container.

That means, i have to generate an `auth_token` using a curl request to `app` service and then add that token as Environment variable `AUTH_TOKEN` for `test` container.

I tried different ways to achieve this:

- Added an init-container `generate-token` for `test` pod, that will generate the token and will save it in a shared volume. And `test` container will have access to that volume. But the problem here is, the `test` container doesn't have a code to set env for the container by reading from the shared volume.
- Added a sidecar-container `sidecar-generate-token` instead of an init-container for the same setup as mentioned above. Here also problem is, the `test` container doesn't have a code to set env for the container by reading from the shared volume. And also, the test pod got into a crashloopbackoff state. If you check the content of volume by getting into the container, there are multiple tokens in the volume file which are generated on each pod restart of crashloopbackoff.
- Third plan was that an init-container `generate-token` should create a kubernetes secret in the cluster, after generating the auth_token. Then the main container `test` can set Environment variable from that secret. For that, the init container `generate-token` should have a kubectl setup in it first.

If i am proceeding with the third plan, How can i setup and use kubectl from init-container to generate secret in the cluster?

Is there any other alternative plan to achieve this goal?

**EDIT:**

---

This is the yaml part for the first option:

```
  initContainers:
    - name: generate-service-token
      image: app.mycr.io/alpine-network-troubleshooting:dev-latest
      command:
      - /bin/sh
      - -c
      - |
        BEARER_TOKEN=$(curl -k -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" --data '{"user":"dynizer","password":"xxxx"}' "https://app:50051/api/v2/login" | jq -r '.jwt')
        SERVICE_TOKEN=$(curl -k -X GET -H 'Accept: application/json' -H "Authorization: Bearer ${BEARER_TOKEN}" "https://app:50051/api/v2/servicetoken/issue" | jq -r '.token')
        echo $SERVICE_TOKEN
        mkdir -p /vol
        touch /vol/token.txt
        echo $SERVICE_TOKEN >> /vol/token.txt
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /vol
          name: token-vol    
  containers:              
    - name: nginx-container
      image: nginx
      volumeMounts:
      - name: token-vol
        mountPath: /vol                                             
  volumes:
    - name: token-vol
      emptyDir: {}
```

Comment: First point seems like it should work. The crashloopbackoff is most probably caused by misconfigured pod. Can you provide the yaml files?

Comment: @Matt Sorry, that crashloopbackoff occurs now when using a side-car container, I edited the question. I'll provide the yaml there. But still the same problem of container not having the code to set env by reading from the shared volume, will be there.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to answer your question:

> But still the same problem of container not having the code to set env by reading from the shared volume, will be there.

Let's try to read this env from other container. Here Is what I have come up with.

First you need to know what command your container is running. In case of nginx that is `/docker-entrypoint.sh nginx -g "daemon off;"` ([source code](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/464886ab21ebe4b036ceb36d7557bf491f6d9320/mainline/debian/Dockerfile#L110-L116))

Then you use `command` field where you read the token value from file and use `env` to set it and run the actual applciation.

Example:

```
  initContainers:
    - name: generate-service-token
      image: app.mycr.io/alpine-network-troubleshooting:dev-latest
      command:
      - /bin/sh
      - -c
      - |
        BEARER_TOKEN=$(curl -k -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" --data '{"user":"dynizer","password":"xxxx"}' "https://app:50051/api/v2/login" | jq -r '.jwt')
        SERVICE_TOKEN=$(curl -k -X GET -H 'Accept: application/json' -H "Authorization: Bearer ${BEARER_TOKEN}" "https://app:50051/api/v2/servicetoken/issue" | jq -r '.token')
        echo $SERVICE_TOKEN
        mkdir -p /vol
        touch /vol/token.txt
        echo $SERVICE_TOKEN >> /vol/token.txt
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /vol
          name: token-vol    
  containers:              
    - name: nginx-container
      image: nginx
      command:
      - sh
      - -c
      - exec env SERVICE_TOKEN=$(cat /vol/token.txt) /docker-entrypoint.sh nginx -g "daemon off;"
      volumeMounts:
      - name: token-vol
        mountPath: /vol                                             
  volumes:
    - name: token-vol
      emptyDir: {}
```

More general example:

```
  command:
  - sh
  - -c
  - exec env SERVICE_TOKEN=$(cat /vol/token.txt) <<any command>>
```

I am not sure if this is the best example, but I hope that at least it gives you an idea how you can approach this problem.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I tried this. But when i try to execute into the pod, and try to `echo $SERVICE_TOKEN`, the value is not printed. That means, env is not set. Right? My actual image is not nginx, but that one also behaves like it cannot find the env.

Comment: You didn't mention anything about execing into a pod. I though all you want to do is to start the main process with SERVICE_TOKEN env. `kubectl exec` wont see the variable.

Comment: `kubectl exec` creates additional shell process which doesn't include variables set for the main container shell process. If you add `echo $VARIABLE_NAME` to the main container shell command and then check `kubectl logs` for that container you should see the variable value there. To set this variable in the `exec` process you should include the same `env SERVICE_TOKEN=$(cat /vol/token.txt)` command when running `exec` shell.